# Проблема с изменением связанных полей в MS SQL2000

Tags: sql, sql-server, сервер

Появилась необходимость в изменении значения поля таблицы (последнее значение подошло к пределу ограничений для типа данных), сложность в том, что оно ключевое и используется еще в 300-500 таблицах, как можно в данном случае их каскадно обновить, удалить кривое значение также не могу, поскольку есть foreign key и их много. Касательно изменения типа, также не прокатывает, т. к. оболочка цепляется именно к определенному типу данных

Answer (score 1):

Внешние ключи с каскадным обновлением решают проблему.
Если же вы поменяете тип данных в EM, то это тоже должно привести к соответствующему изменению типов данных в связанных таблицах. Предварительно можно посмотреть генерируемый при этом код.

Comment: не прокатывает, т. к. оболочка цепляется именно к типу данных поля с изменяемым значением

Comment: Что именно не "прокатывает"? Изменение типа?
Тогда остается каскадное обновление.

Comment: Не прокатывает то, что оболочка, написанная на VB разработчиком и БД и оболочки цепляется к типу, что касается каскадного обновления, как я понял, нужно пересоздавать все FK, а их более 500

Comment: > нужно пересоздавать все FK, а их более 500

Тогда придется написать скрипт, который изменит внешние ключи во всех связанных таблицах, используя динамический sql.
Можно еще уволиться. :-)

Comment: Ей богу, последнее больше нравится

Comment: Тогда отметьте этот вариант как лучший ответ. :-)